# Ni-Cd battery voltage indication of 100% charge

Tags: nicd-battery

I have a Ni-Cd battery of 1.2 V.

- What is the voltage when it is 100% charged and for 0%?
- What does that 1.2 V indicate?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what will be the voltage in ni-cd battery if charged 100%.

Answer (score 2):

The nominal voltage of the Ni-Cd type battery is 1.2V, which is used to build your system.

For example, if you have a 110V DC system you calculate the number of cells you required using the nominal voltage which is (110 / 1.2) 92 cells.

But normal working conditions are not the same because it is usually working on the float charge of 1.40V (It depends on the type of Ni-Cd battery but most commonly 1.40V ~ 1.42V) and boost charge 1.45V.

If your batteries are not brand new so in this case voltage can be delusive about your fullness of batteries. Even in stored brand new batteries, there will be some capacity loss after not charging them for 6 months.

The correct way to understand is your batteries are full or not is by watching the drawn current.

So the way to understand your batteries are full or not you should connect them to the charger and set it to boost level 1.45V (please refer to your battery datasheet and use that value if that is different and also be sure that your charger has a current limitation and set it to 20% of your Ah value e.g. if your battery is 100Ah set it to max 20A) and watch the drained current. If it comes near to zero then your batteries are full.
After batteries are full you need to disconnect from the charger and when you measure battery voltage it will show you the full capacity voltage of your battery.

Comment: This shows a better than average understanding of NiCd cells. The peak charge voltage also varies with charge C rate. Choose too high a voltage at a given C rate and it will never terminate.

Answer (score 0):

For Nickel Cadmium batteries, assuming you charge at a consistent rate between 0.3-1C, you will see a sudden drop of 2-5mV across the battery terminals once it reaches a fully charged state,

1.2V is the voltage produced by the chemical energy in the cell, its mostly a flat discharge curve, but there is still a slight slope if you where to measure with enough resolution, if you drain the battery close to flat, that voltage will begin to fall towards 0V,

Comment: *Towards* zero, yes, but discharge of a NiCd should be ceased when the *unloaded* voltage drops to 1.1 volts.